# List Azure Resources By Tag Using Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-java-sdk

Is there a way to get list of resources or resource groups using values assigned on tags using Java SDK?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use method [`listByTag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.resources.fluentcore.collection._supports_listing_by_tag.listbytag) to list resource by Tag. Like below:

```
PagedList<ResourceGroup> group = azure.resourceGroups().listByTag("shuitest", "shui");
```

Also, you could check this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-resources/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/resources/implementation/ResourceGroupsImpl.java#L45).

Comment: Example is 404.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Management for Resources available part of Azure SDK for Java

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/azure-mgmt-resources

or use plain REST API's

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/ResourceGroups/List and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups

Comment: First link is 404.